# Apply style to more than one element

Tags: css

This is an easy one, but i can no find the right way to do this. I have the following style definition:

```
.main_section nav a {
    color:#999;
    ...
}
```

So this style applies to the `a` in the `nav` in the `.main_section`. Now I want to extend this so that also `li` elements are affected. What I would do is to duplicate the code, like:

```
.main_section nav li {
    color:#999;
    ...
}
```

But this just feels wrong. I want to unify both style specs into one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use comma `(,)` to define same style on multiple elements

```
.main_section nav a,.main_section nav li {
    color:#999;
    ...
}
```

Comment: And I have to repeat the whole thing? Not possible to do something like `.main_section nav (a,li)`?

Comment: @gonvaled still better than repeating the whole styling for each element I think :P

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a CSS preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Using one of these you would be able to write your code like the following:

```
.main_section {
    nav {
        a,
        li {
            color: #999;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.main_section nav a, .main_section nav li 
{
   color:#999;
    ...

}
```